# Column misalignment in grid

Tags: html, alignment

I am having difficulty aligning my columns in my grid. I just cant figure out why columns are not aligning. First i thought its due to scroll bar but even if i remove scroll bar i cant get columns to align. This is my html code

```
<div>
<div>
    <table class="gridHover" style="margin-bottom: 0; table-layout: fixed; border-bottom: 1px solid #000;" border="1">
        <colgroup>
            <col style="width: 120px;">
                <col style="width: 60px;">
                    <col style="width: 50px;">
                        <col style="width: 70px;">
                            <col style="width: 70px;">
                                <col style="width: 50px;">
                                    <col style="width: 100px;">
                                        <col style="width: 100px;">
                                            <col>
        </colgroup>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>First Col</th>
                <th>Second col</th>
                <th>Third col</th>
                <th>Fourth col</th>
                <th>Fift col</th>
                <th>Sixth col</th>
                <th>seventh col</th>
                <th>eigth col</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
    <div style="overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden; height: 480px;">
        <table class="gridHover" id="gridData" border="1" style="table-layout:fixed">
            <colgroup>
                <col style="width: 120px;">
                    <col style="width: 60px;">
                        <col style="width: 50px;">
                            <col style="width: 70px;">
                                <col style="width: 70px;">
                                    <col style="width: 50px;">
                                        <col style="width: 100px;">
                                            <col style="width: 100px;">
                                                <col>
            </colgroup>
            <tbody class="table table-hover">
                <tr>
                    <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">Tom cruise</span>

                    </td>
                    <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">AB</span>

                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;"> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">1</span>

                    </td>
                    <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">7</span>

                    </td>
                    <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">1</span>

                    </td>
                    <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word"></span>

                    </td>
                    <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word"></span>

                    </td>
                    <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">CCC </span>

                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">Arnold</span>

                    </td>
                    <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">AB</span>

                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;"> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">1</span>

                    </td>
                    <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">7</span>

                    </td>
                    <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">1</span>

                    </td>
                    <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word"></span>

                    </td>
                    <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word"></span>

                    </td>
                    <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">CCC </span>

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4KB3C/36/) which could be easy for you guys to help me out.

You can see that output is different in chrome and IE and i really dont understand why is it like that.

Comment: Why do you have 9 <col>'s defined, but only 8 <th> and <td>?  Have you tried to remove the last <col> without any style applied?

Comment: @Michael yes i removed empty col but doesnt help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My last attempt on this topic. I have used fixed width and I think it works out. If you can't define a certain % value you might need to use different fix values for different screen resolutions / devices. Fiddle at the bottom of the post.

CSS Code (Changed .gridHover {width: 640px;}

```
    .overflow {
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 480px;"    
}

.gridHover {
    width: 640px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.gridHover th, .gridHover td {
    padding: 8px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
.gridHover th {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.gridHover thead th {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

HTML CODE (changed it to the original 8 col layout again):

```
<div>
    <div>
        <table class="gridHover" style="margin-bottom: 0; table-layout: fixed; border-bottom: 1px solid #000;"  border="1">
            <colgroup>
                <col style="width: 120px;">
                    <col style="width: 60px;">
                        <col style="width: 50px;">
                            <col style="width: 70px;">
                                <col style="width: 70px;">
                                    <col style="width: 50px;">
                                        <col style="width: 100px;">
                                            <col style="width: 100px;">

            </colgroup>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="width: 120px;">First Col</th>
                    <th style="width: 60px;">Second col</th>
                    <th style="width: 50px;">Third col</th>
                    <th style="width: 70px;">Fourth col</th>
                    <th style="width: 70px;">Fift col</th>
                    <th style="width: 50px;">Sixth col</th>
                    <th style="width: 100px;">seventh col</th>
                    <th style="width: 100px;">eigth col</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
        <div class="overflow">
            <table class="gridHover" id="gridData" border="1" style="table-layout:fixed">
                <colgroup>
                    <col style="width: 120px;">
                        <col style="width: 60px;">
                            <col style="width: 50px;">
                                <col style="width: 70px;">                                    <col style="width: 70px;">
                                        <col style="width: 50px;">
                                            <col style="width: 100px;">
                                                <col style="width: 100px;">

                </colgroup>
                <tbody class="table table-hover">
                    <tr>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">Tom cruise</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">AB</span>

                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;"> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">1</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">7</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">1</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word"></span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word"></span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">CCC </span>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">Arnold</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">AB</span>

                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;"> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">1</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">7</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">1</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word"></span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word"></span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">CCC </span>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">Arnold</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">AB</span>

                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;"> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">1</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">7</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">1</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word"></span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word"></span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">CCC </span>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">Arnold</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">AB</span>

                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;"> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">1</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">7</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">1</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word"></span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word"></span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">CCC </span>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">Arnold</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">AB</span>

                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;"> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">1</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">7</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">1</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word"></span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word"></span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">CCC </span>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">Arnold</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">AB</span>

                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;"> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">1</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">7</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">1</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word"></span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word"></span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">CCC </span>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">Arnold</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">AB</span>

                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;"> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">1</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">7</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">1</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word"></span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word"></span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">CCC </span>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">Arnold</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">AB</span>

                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;"> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">1</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">7</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">1</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word"></span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word"></span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">CCC </span>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">Arnold</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">AB</span>

                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;"> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">1</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">7</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">1</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word"></span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word"></span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">CCC </span>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">Arnold</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">AB</span>

                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;"> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">1</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">7</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">1</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word"></span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word"></span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">CCC </span>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">Arnold</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">AB</span>

                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;"> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">1</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">7</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">1</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word"></span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word"></span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">CCC </span>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">Arnold</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">AB</span>

                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;"> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">1</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">7</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">1</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word"></span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word"></span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">CCC </span>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">Arnold</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">AB</span>

                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;"> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">1</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">7</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">1</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word"></span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word"></span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">CCC </span>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">Arnold</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">AB</span>

                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;"> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">1</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">7</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">1</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word"></span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word"></span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">CCC </span>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">Arnold</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">AB</span>

                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;"> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">1</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">7</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">1</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word"></span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word"></span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">CCC </span>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">Arnold</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">AB</span>

                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;"> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">1</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">7</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">1</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word"></span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word"></span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">CCC </span>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">Arnold</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">AB</span>

                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;"> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">1</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">7</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">1</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word"></span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word"></span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">CCC </span>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">Arnold</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">AB</span>

                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;"> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">1</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">7</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">1</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word"></span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word"></span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">CCC </span>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">Arnold</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">AB</span>

                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;"> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">1</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">7</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">1</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word"></span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word"></span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">CCC </span>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">Arnold</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">AB</span>

                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;"> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">1</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">7</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">1</span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word"></span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word"></span>

                        </td>
                        <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">CCC </span>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

You can check the result in this fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/4KB3C/56

Comment: you are almost there but i want to know if i manually set width to 640px to table using gridhover class and dont change css of gridhover then why it doesnt work. see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4KB3C/69/
Because this gridhover is used in so many places in my application that i didnt wanted to change. can we do something in this?

Comment: I don't get what you want to archieve now. what about using another css class for whatever part of the table you want to change?

Comment: but you can see that gridhover class is also applied to th,td, so its difficult to change.

Comment: Why do you use such a style definition --> <table class="gridHover" id="gridData" border="1" style="table-layout:fixed;width:640px"> and CSS via classes in parallel. I suggest to work with classes or IDs and remove the style definitions from the html code.

Comment: Problem is that grid is nothing but widget and is used all over in my application, so i cant use ID.

Comment: Let me know asap if its possible so i can award you bounty otherwise it will go waste

Comment: Here's an example with fix style definitions in both tables. Is that what you need? http://jsfiddle.net/4KB3C/70/

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry if I am wrong or not sure for what you're trying to achieve. But, in my opinion, you can set the width of each columns in the second and the third rows with the same size with all column in your first row, so that the table is aligned. You can set the size directly in the "TH" markup.

```
        <thead style="align:centre; margin:auto;">
            <tr>
                <th style="width: 120px;">First Col</th>
                <th style="width: 60px;">Second col</th>
                <th style="width: 50px;">Third col</th>
                <th style="width: 70px;">Fourth col</th>
                <th style="width: 70px;">Fift col</th>
                <th style="width: 50px;">Sixth col</th>
                <th style="width: 100px;">seventh col</th>
                <th style="width: 100px;">eigth col</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
```

And

```
                    <td style="width: 120px;"> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">Tom cruise</span>

                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 120px;"> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">AB</span>

                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 120px;"> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">1</span>

                    </td>
```

Comment: You have to delete all your col markups first. http://jsfiddle.net/Alkasih/YPW47/1/

Comment: First, I think it's a little complicated for us to see that the width is set to which col, by set it directly to your th or td markup you can see it clearly. And last, it is the first time I find people use it in customizing table, and thank you for that.

Comment: Also i cant hard code width of those 2 rows because the html you see is a plugin and its used by other code. so i cant hard code it.

Comment: I will try to help, but I just found an example here that maybe can help you too. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_colgroup_width thank you for voting up. :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Alkasih/LFDjd/ here with colgroup.. I will to fix it with your code but it will need about 15 minutes from now

Comment: It looks like those css which i have used in my fiddle are causing this issue. If i just remove css from my original fiddle then it shows fine. so what could be wrong there?

Comment: DONE! http://jsfiddle.net/Alkasih/Pnn56/ the problem is only with the line-height, the padding and the max widht that you set.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Alkasih/Pnn56/3/ this is what I can give for now. I am sorry.

Comment: can you see if you are able to find solution. If you are able to solve then you can get 50 reputation

Answer (score 1):

The first thing is, that a closing  is missing. You also shouldn't set width to more than max-width!

To your problem now:

Just remove your **"overflow-y: scroll; "** from the div containing the second table and you are ready to go...

I think that's all you need to do.

Comment: see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4KB3C/54/

i removed overflow-y but still column shifts

Comment: Ok, I think I found a solution: Add "display: table;" to both of your table elements! (you can remove overflow-y)

Comment: check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4KB3C/57/  i have added display:table but still same issue

Comment: Oh sorry, my fault, for the 2nd table you have to add the "display: table;" to the parent div (the parent of the 2nd table!!!) http://jsfiddle.net/b4FtW/

Answer (score 0):

You are using two different tables. that's why you are getting the alignment issue. I suppose this is what you require.

http://jsfiddle.net/4KB3C/35/

```
<div>
<div>
    <table class="gridHover" style="margin-bottom: 0; border-bottom: 1px solid #000;" border="1">
        <colgroup>
            <col style="width: 120px;">
                <col style="width: 60px;">
                    <col style="width: 50px;">
                        <col style="width: 70px;">
                            <col style="width: 70px;">
                                <col style="width: 50px;">
                                    <col style="width: 100px;">
                                        <col style="width: 100px;">
                                            <col>
        </colgroup>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>First Col</th>
                <th>Second col</th>
                <th>Third col</th>
                <th>Fourth col</th>
                <th>Fift col</th>
                <th>Sixth col</th>
                <th>seventh col</th>
                <th>eigth col</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
    <div style="overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden; height: 480px;">
        <table class="gridHover" id="gridData" border="1">
            <colgroup>
                <col style="width: 120px;">
                    <col style="width: 60px;">
                        <col style="width: 50px;">
                            <col style="width: 70px;">
                                <col style="width: 70px;">
                                    <col style="width: 50px;">
                                        <col style="width: 100px;">
                                            <col style="width: 100px;">
                                                <col>
            </colgroup>
            <tbody class="table table-hover">
                <tr>
                    <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">Tom cruise</span>

                    </td>
                    <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">AB</span>

                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;"> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">1</span>

                    </td>
                    <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">7</span>

                    </td>
                    <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">1</span>

                    </td>
                    <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word"></span>

                    </td>
                    <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word"></span>

                    </td>
                    <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">CCC </span>

                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">Arnold</span>

                    </td>
                    <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">AB</span>

                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;"> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">1</span>

                    </td>
                    <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">7</span>

                    </td>
                    <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">1</span>

                    </td>
                    <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word"></span>

                    </td>
                    <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word"></span>

                    </td>
                    <td> <span style="word-wrap: break-word">CCC </span>

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The alignment in your fiddle is not correct and also get horizontal scrolling bar which is wrong

Comment: Why have you removed scroll bar and also removed width?

Comment: You require width to be specified irrespective of resolution?

Comment: Yes i need width to be specified

Comment: can you see if you are able to find solution. If you are able to solve then you can get 50 reputation

Answer (score 0):

Change the max width to 100%, because it doesn't make sense if the original widht is smaller than the max widht.

```
.gridHover {
width: 100%;
margin-bottom: 20px;
max-width: 100%; 
}
```

I delete your padding that cause your table width to be minimized by that, and the line-height that is a little annoying.

```
.gridHover th, .gridHover td {
text-align: left;
vertical-align: top;
border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
```

Comment: Its strange that you are able to post 2 answers to same question :)